# Find parent of an element using Xpath in Appium

Tags: java, android, xpath, automated-tests, appium

This question is quite popular, but the answers I found do not work for me.

So, I have the following code snippet:

```
MobileElement room = driver.findElement (By.xpath ("//android.widget.TextView[@text = 'Test Room']"));
//Doing some stuff with the room element
MobileElement roomContainer = room.findElement (By.xpath ("./.."));
```

I get the `room` variable, do some stuff with it. Then I try to search for the parent of this element, but I get `NoSuchElement` exception.

I tried different combinations of Xpath, none of them worked:

```
".//..",  "//..",  "/..",  ".."
```

However, when I search from the driver using the whole query, it works:

```
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("//android.widget.TextView[@text = 'Test Room']/.."))
```

But in this particular case I need to search from the `room` element directly. Any advice?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: **./..** is the correct expression to jump to the immediate parent. As you have already mentioned it is not working, try using **parent** function in Xpath. Please add the html, so that it will help you to get proper responses.

Comment: Can you try  '../..' it to point parent node?

Comment: @Sooraj
There is no HTML in Android. I'm using Appium, not Selenium.

Comment: @Muzzamil Tried, did not work.

Comment: @LexSav, Sorry, I meant the App Source

Comment: @LexSav Can you please post appium inspector image? This parent has single child?

Comment: @Sooraj added screenshot

Comment: @Muzzamil added screenshot

Comment: Has anyone found solution? I have same issue in Appium-Python-Client==2.0.0 (selenium 4.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below Xpath:

`MobileElement roomContainer = room.findElement(By.xpath("./parent::android.view.ViewGroup"));`

Comment: As I already mentioned, the full Xpath works: `"//android.widget.TextView[@text = 'Test Room']/.."`. I'm interested in how I can go up one node from the specific element directly: `room.findElement (By.xpath ("./.."));`

Comment: Did not work :( Tried different variations with dots and slashes. Also, tried some variations with `parent` and `parent::node()` - the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Although you are able to locate parents node with below xpath as per your question.

```
driver.findElement (By.xpath ("//android.widget.TextView[@text = 'Test Room']/.."))
```

But you want to locate parent node from current child node with `./..` instead writing full xpath for parent node.

We can achieve it with in reverse approach, we can write full xpath for parent and we can find child node inside parent node instead full page or DOM.

```
MobileElement roomContainer = driver.findElement (By.xpath ("//android.widget.TextView[@text = 'Test Room']/.."))

MobileElement room = roomContainer.findElement (By.xpath ("//android.widget.TextView[@text = 'Test Room']"));

OR

MobileElement room = roomContainer.findElement (By.id ("item_rooms_list_tv_room_name]"));
```

Note: Parent node also have resource id for locate but I am  not sure it is unique as I can’t see other 2 `viewGroup` nodes so I have used xpath for parent node.

Comment: I see. So there is no way to go up one node from the child element to the parent? We can go only from parent to child and that's all?

Comment: @LexSav We can go to parent node and I use ./.. for it in appium-andriod and selenium. but its not working in your case, I can't say why it is happening? But I tried to provide you similar solution but with different approach.

Answer (score -1):

Try with `"//.."`

Example:
You have child_element

your Code should looks like this:

```
child_element.findElement(By.xpath("//..")) should get parent
```

Comment: please add description to your answer, i have not  realized what you are suggesting